# Crashed upgrade form 13.10 to 14.04

Tags: upgrade, sound, system-installation, intel-graphics

Today, I turned on my computer and upgrade Ubuntu to 14.04, since it is so long, so I went to have dinner. When I'm back, the screen freeze(I tried to move my mouse, but the mouse icon moved a few minutes later). I left it for an hour and finally force reboot the computer.
I searched in forums and found a way to continue the upgrade(enter recovery mode shell and `dpkg --configure -a` however, when I reboot the computer again, the screen resolution seemed to be increased(the images looked to be more meticulous) but after I login, the mouse responded slower than that before update. The system also seemed to be laggy. After few minute my cpu reached 70°C!!!(That's my bios alarm) ,also, there is a small icon on the upper bar showing something like "...packet damaged...type apt-get in terminal" some thing like this, after I did `sudo aptitude build-dep` ,showing a lot on unsolved dependence. 
I don't know what to do to or if there is "reupgrade command" Please help!
Edit:After successfully solve dependence, I found out the following problems:
1. No hardware acceleration(poor graphics with high cup usage, I can only set the resolution lower to prevent cup burn), however I tried to install driver again, not helping.
2. Play.ape file in cmus will crackling, noise will come out when playing .m4a (however, they can be played in vlc, but my bios scream for high temperature again after I play a few songs...)
I think I left some important packages during this damaged upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know you're level of experience, or knowledge of Linux, so if it seems I'm being simple, don't take it personally. 
In my opinion, the best way to keep a certain distro (that is not a rolling release) is to make sure the `/ (root directory)` and `/home (home directory)`, this way when a new version comes out, I can install the new version on the same drives/partitions, formatting the root partition, and NOT formatting the home partition. This way you can install it, and you still have all you files and settings, you just need to install your apps again, which is the only real downside.

Now if you used the Ubuntu update tool, when you left, and let it go by itself, there may have been issues which you were not there to see, and correct. You should always stay when doing something as important as  upgrading your entire OS.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, however, I was inspired by your response, I cam wait for next release of ubuntu and so I can upgrade again to repair it.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar issue when going from 13.04 to 13.10.

To fix unmet depedency hell, boot into a terminal and type

`sudo apt-get -f install`

The `f` parameter here means it will try to fix broken dependencies. It is likely this will end with something like `and x not upgraded`. Now you must run:

`sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

This will install new packages for packages that changed their dependencies between 13.10 and 14.04.

While installing, it is unfortunately important to keep an eye on it! There will be quite many packages who will ask some configuration options during installation (just use the default if you're unsure what to do). Installation will hang until you give an answer.

After everything is finished, run

`sudo apt-get autoclean` and `sudo apt-get autoremove` to remove now-redundant files and packages.

Hope this helps :-).